# Pandas get the most frequent values of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have this dataframe:

```
0 name data
1 alex asd
2 helen sdd
3 alex dss
4 helen sdsd
5 john sdadd
```

so i am trying to get ***the most frequent value or values(in this case its values)***
so what i do is:

```
dataframe['name'].value_counts().idxmax()
```

but it returns only the value: **Alex** even if it **Helen** appears two times as well.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

By using `mode`

```
df.name.mode()
Out[712]: 
0     alex
1    helen
dtype: object
```

Comment: Hmmm, I have seen you using mode earlier :)

Comment: @Vaishali yep, that is from scipy.mode , which will return the mode and the count , for pd.mode, it one return the value :-)

Comment: is there a way to get both the most frequent value and its indices with one query?

Comment: @user2348209 you can but not recommend `df.reset_index().groupby(df['name'])['index'].agg(list).loc[lambda x : x.str.len() ==x.str.len().max()]
`

Answer (score 93):

To get the `n` most frequent values, just subset `.value_counts()` and grab the index:

```
# get top 10 most frequent names
n = 10
dataframe['name'].value_counts()[:n].index.tolist()
```

Comment: What exactly does adding .index does? Why can't I leave it till [:n]?

Comment: The returned data structure will have the `name` values stored in the index, with their respective counts stored as the value. So if you didn't use index, you'd get a list of the most frequent counts, not the associated `name`.

Answer (score 18):

You could try `argmax` like this:

`dataframe['name'].value_counts().argmax()
Out[13]: 'alex'`

The `value_counts` will return a count object of `pandas.core.series.Series` and `argmax` could be used to achieve the key of max values.

Comment: `argmax` is deprecated for `idmax`

Comment: Just a small typo correction: is not ```idmax```, but ```idxmax```

Answer (score 13):

It will give top five most common names:

```
df['name'].value_counts().nlargest(5)
```

Answer (score 11):

```
df['name'].value_counts()[:5].sort_values(ascending=False)
```

The `value_counts` will return a count object of `pandas.core.series.Series` and `sort_values(ascending=False)` will get you the highest values first.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: `value_counts()` already returns a sort in descending order, so calling `sort_values()` is unnecessary. See [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html).

Answer (score 11):

Use:

```
df['name'].mode()
```

or

```
df['name'].value_counts().idxmax()
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use this to get a perfect count, it calculates the mode a particular column

```
df['name'].value_counts()
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's one way:

```
df['name'].value_counts()[df['name'].value_counts() == df['name'].value_counts().max()]
```

which prints:

```
helen    2
alex     2
Name: name, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 6):

**Not Obvious, But Fast**

```
f, u = pd.factorize(df.name.values)
counts = np.bincount(f)
u[counts == counts.max()]

array(['alex', 'helen'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: For numeric data, this was slightly slower for me :) Like 5%

Answer (score 5):

to get top 5:

```
dataframe['name'].value_counts()[0:5]
```

Comment: I actually like this answer, but there is one issue. Doing this just returns the frequency, not the label. Fix this by using ```dataframe['name'].value_counts().keys()[0:5]``` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Simply use this..

```py
dataframe['name'].value_counts().nlargest(n)
```

The functions for frequencies largest and smallest are:

- `nlargest()` for mostfrequent 'n' values
- `nsmallest()` for least frequent 'n' values

Answer (score 3):

You could use .apply and pd.value_counts to get a count the occurrence of all the names in the name column.

```
dataframe['name'].apply(pd.value_counts)
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the top five most common names:

```
dataframe['name'].value_counts().head()
```

Answer (score 2):

my best solution to get the first is

```
 df['my_column'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False).argmax()
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue best most compact answer to get lets say the top n (5 is default) most frequent values is:

```
df["column_name"].value_counts().head(n)
```

Answer (score 2):

Identifying the top 5, for example, using value_counts

```
top5 = df['column'].value_counts()
```

Listing contents of 'top_5'

```
top5[:5]
```

Comment: The one liner for this is:  `df['column'].value_counts()[:5]`

Comment: The above may give you a `KeyError`. The more general way is `top5.keys()[:5]`
The one-liner being `df['column'].value_counts().keys()[:5]`

Answer (score 1):

## n is used to get the number of top frequent used items

```
n = 2

a=dataframe['name'].value_counts()[:n].index.tolist()

dataframe["name"].value_counts()[a]
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting top 5 most common lastname pandas:

```
df['name'].apply(lambda name: name.split()[-1]).value_counts()[:5]
```