# Counting same entries per group in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in the following form:

```
group base height weight size
0      A     10     5     M
0      A     20     5     M
1      A     10     10    S
2      A      5      5    L
```

How can I get a matrix, which counts the similiar entries by group? The output looks like this:

```
compare  base height weight size
0,1        3/3  2/3   2/3   2/3
0,2        3/3  0/3   3/3   2/3
1,2        2/2  0/2   0/2   0/2
```

Comment: You might solicit a better answer if you post your code as well :)

Comment: Only solution I have in mind so far is to work column per column and group by group, that would fill probably one page here, that would lead to some confusion.

Comment: How big is your data?

Comment: shape is: (117764, 39), but i probably want to compare only some columns out of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- at the core of the solution [most frequent values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48590268/pandas-get-the-most-frequent-values-of-a-column/48590361)
- use `itertools.combinations` to get valid pairs of groups
- compare **most frequent** to each row in combination of groups. `sum()` truth matrix to find number of matches
- rest is formating

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""group base height weight size
0      A     10     5     M
0      A     20     5     M
1      A     10     10    S
2      A      5      5    L"""), sep="\s+")

# columns we're working with
cols = [c for c in df.columns if c!= "group"]

# iterate over combinations of groups
dfx = pd.DataFrame()
for gp in itertools.combinations(df.group.unique(), 2):
    dfg = df.loc[df.group.isin(gp),cols]
    dfx = pd.concat([dfx, 
                     (dfg == dfg.value_counts().index[0])
                     .sum().to_frame().T.assign(gs=len(dfg), compare=",".join(str(e) for e in gp))
                    ])
# rebase 1 as 0 for comparisons
dfx = dfx.reset_index(drop=True).replace(1,0).astype(str)
# format as required
dfx.loc[:,cols] = dfx[cols].apply(lambda x: x+" / " +dfx["gs"])

dfx.drop(columns="gs")
```

|  | base | height | weight | size | compare |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 / 3 | 2 / 3 | 2 / 3 | 2 / 3 | 0,1 |
| 1 | 3 / 3 | 0 / 3 | 3 / 3 | 0 / 3 | 0,2 |
| 2 | 2 / 2 | 0 / 2 | 0 / 2 | 0 / 2 | 1,2 |