# Change values of a column based on most frequently value on other column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have an `pandas.DataFrame` like that:

```py
expl = {'label':['A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','C','A','A'],
'predicted':[1,1,3,2,2,1,3,2,3,4,4,-1,-2]}

        }
myDf = DataFrame(expl)
```

I wanna to  create a new column with the values on 'predicted' column but  "renamed" with  the most frequently values on 'predicted' from each 'label'.

I'm currently using the following code which works as expected:

```py
for group in myDf['predicted'].unique():
    if group >=0:
        dfg  = myDf.loc[myDf['predicted']==group, ['label']]
        rename = myDf.loc[myDf['predicted']==group, ['label']].groupby(['label']).size().idxmax()
        myDf.loc[myDf['predicted']==group,'renamed']= rename
    else:
        myDf.loc[myDf['predicted']==group,'renamed']= 'NA'
```

But I don't think it's the best way to do this. Is there any way to do this better?(in speed or memory)

I also think in save the most frequently values on a `dict` and use `myDf['predict'].apply(lambda v: d[v] )` to replace the values, but doesn't seem to be faster.

**Note**: Negative values will be considered Not Available(`'NA'`).

Expected Output:

```
    label   predicted   renamed
0   A   1   A
1   A   1   A
2   A   3   C
3   B   2   B
4   B   2   B
5   B   1   A
6   C   3   C
7   C   2   B
8   C   3   C
9   C   4   C
10  C   4   C
11  A   -1  NA
12  A   -2  NA
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48590268/pandas-get-the-most-frequent-values-of-a-column/48590361

Comment: @politinsa  my problem not is just on get the most frequently, but how to create the new column with this values with in a good performance. It's not the same problem as the stack you sent

Comment: Then look at most common value with groupby: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222754/groupby-pandas-dataframe-and-select-most-common-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `groupby()`+`transform()` and calculate the mode and use `mask()` to create NaN where 'predicted' is negative number:

```
myDf['renamed']=(myDf.groupby('predicted')['label']
                    .transform(lambda x:x.mode().iloc[0])
                    .mask(myDf['predicted'].le(-1)))
```

Comment: Nice, that way perform at least 10 time faster in my test case. Thank you, I will study these methods further.