# Getting highest value out of a dataframe with value_counts()

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to print out the highest, not unique value out of my dataframe.
With df['Value'].value_counts() i can count them, but how do i selected them by how often the numbers appear.

| Value |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 2 |

Comment: You might want to refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48590268/pandas-get-the-most-frequent-values-of-a-column/48590361

Comment: My table is a bad example because 2 is in my case the second highest value and also the most frequent one. In that case your answere would help. But if 1 is the most frequent one and 3 the highest there is no solution on the question you linked.

Comment: You want the answer to be 3 in that case because it is the maximum value, right?

Comment: i want to check if the highest value is more then once in the dataframe, if so i just want to print it. If not i want to check if the second highest value is more then once in my dataframe.

Comment: I think I understand. You can see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want the first highest value that has a frequency greater than 1. In this case you can write,

```
for val, cnt in df['Value'].value_counts().sort_index(ascending=False).iteritems():
  if cnt > 1:
    print(val)
    break
```

The sort_index sorts the items by the 'Value' rather than the frequencies. For example if your 'Value' columns has values [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2,2, 1, 3, 2] then the result of `df['Value'].value_counts().sort_index(ascending=False).iteritems()` will be as follows,

```
3    3
2    5
1    2
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

The answer in this example would then be 3 since it is the first highest value with frequency greater than 1.

Comment: I want the combination. if the max is for example just once in the dataframe and the second highest two times i want to print out the second highest.

Comment: I have edited the above answer. You can check that.

Comment: Thank you. Exacly what i was looking for

Comment: And ascending=True gives me the lowest value with frequency greater than 1?

Comment: Yes, it will then loop in the reverse order.