# filter column of a dataframe by the two fields that are repeated the most

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and values are repeated in a column called label, I want to show only the two that are repeated the most........

I attach an image as an example

I tried

```
# the name of colums is label

# the name of dataframe is pd_data

filter = \['a','b'\]
pd_data = pd_data\[\~pd_data.labels.isin(filter)\]

print(len(pd_data))
pd_data.groupby('label').size().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas get the most frequent values of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48590268/pandas-get-the-most-frequent-values-of-a-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html#pandas.DataFrame.value_counts)

```
pd_data.value_counts()
```

or

```
pd_data.groupby(['label']).count()
```

Comment: But I need delete the rest of values and save the two firts with more values

Comment: All you have to do is slicing the part you need like this: 
df = pd_data.groupby(['label']).count() 
new_df = df[:2]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas.Series.value_counts()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to get the counts of unique values in Series, then slicing the Series with top 2

```py
pd_data['label'].value_counts()[:1]
```

Comment: perfect, thank you 

pd_data['label'].value_counts()[:2]

Comment: But I need delete the rest of values and save the two firts with more values